# Hosting android app on a server

Tags: android, database, client-server

I'm a new to android so I don't know a lot of things you can do with a android application. 
My main question is: Can you host an android application on a server then call it from another application when requested? 
Can anyone recommend tutorial or an article about android application communicating with servers.

Or is there another way to store and use large databases that aren't stored in app itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android App can use any means available via TCP or UDP to communicate over the internet. HTTP is also built-in. Other/higher layer protocols (SOAP, ...) may need additional libraries to be added to your App, of which there are many readily available to choose from.

The point is: Almost any kind of client/server communcation can be implemented in an Android App; select one that fits your purpose and chances are that there is already a library available for it.

Running an actual Android App (.apk) on a *server* does not make any sense.